# Solr doesn't add a german language char to the field?

Tags: python-3.x, solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

***This is my python code:***

```
cmd = "curl localhost:8983/solr/" + core + "/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary " + "\"[{'id':'" + getLastAddedDocumentID(
        'id') + "','title':{'set':'" + title + "'},'author':{'set':'" + authorNames + "'},'abstract':{'set':'" + abstract + "'}}]\""
    print cmd
    pp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    text, err = pp.communicate()
    print text
```

***My variable cmd which contains Curl command to add the data to fields is as below:***

```
curl localhost:8983/solr/test/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary 
"[{'id':'15973569-229c-4ce1-83e2-4f5ba543386f',
    'title':{'set':'Bi\-criteria\ Algorithm\ for\ Scheduling\ Jobs\ on\ Cluster\ Platforms\ \*'},
    'author':{'set':'Pierre\-François\ Dutot\;\ Lionel\ Eyraud\;\ Grégory\ Gr´\;\ Grégory\ Mouní\;\ Denis\ Trystram\;\ '},
    'abstract':{'set':'We\ describe\ in\ this\ paper\ a\ new\ method\ for\ building\ an\ efficient\ algorithm\ for\ scheduling\ jobs\ in\ a\ cluster.\ Jobs\ are\ considered\ as\ parallel\ tasks\ \(PT\)\ which\ can\ be\ scheduled\ on\ any\ number\ of\ processors.\ The\ main\ feature\ is\ to\ consider\ two\ criteria\ that\ are\ optimized\ together.\ These\ criteria\ are\ the\ makespan\ and\ the\ weighted\ minimal\ average\ completion\ time\ \(minsum\).\ They\ are\ chosen\ for\ their\ complementarity,\ to\ be\ able\ to\ represent\ both\ user\-oriented\ objectives\ and\ system\ administrator\ objectives.\ We\ propose\ an\ algorithm\ based\ on\ a\ batch\ policy\ with\ increasing\ batch\ sizes,\ with\ a\ smart\ selection\ of\ jobs\ in\ each\ batch.\ This\ algorithm\ is\ assessed\ by\ intensive\ simulation\ results,\ compared\ to\ a\ new\ lower\ bound\ \(obtained\ by\ a\ relaxation\ of\ ILP\)\ of\ the\ optimal\ schedules\ for\ both\ criteria\ separately.\ It\ is\ currently\ implemented\ in\ an\ actual\ real\-size\ cluster\ platform.'}}]"
```

***The field abstract is as below:***

```
<field name="abstract" type="string" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

***The problem which I face when running this command is:***

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```
>
> File "F:/pyCalculation/uploadResearchPaper.py", line 196, in 
>      addDocument(pathToResearchPapersFolder + department + '/', query, >department)
>    File "F:/pyCalculation/uploadResearchPaper.py", line 188, in addDocument
>      pp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in **init**
>      errread, errwrite)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 610, in _execute_child
>      args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position >267: ordinal not in range(128)

***And the line at position 276 is:***

> 'set':'Pierre-François\ Dutot\;

The problem is with ç this character.

I am confused like Why doesn't solr allow to add this data to the field?

Answer (score 0):

This is python complaining about your character not being convertible to the ascii codec when trying to invoke a subprocess call. But *please* [use a python Solr client](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr) when connecting to Solr from python, don't invoke curl through subprocess as you would on the command line.

That should solve your problem as well, as long as your data is in unicode (and since you've tagged it as python3, as long as it's a str, it is).

The `set` command is also for modifying an existing document, so if this is the first time you're indexing the document, you do not need the `set` parts of your document structure.